# How do I run PL/SQL queries against MYSQL database?

Tags: mysql, plsql

I have connected my MySQL database to SQL developer using 3rd party JDBC drivers. Also on the right hand side, I selected my MySQL database, but whenever I run any PL/SQL queries, I'm getting a syntax error on `DECLARE`.

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE
  incentive   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT salary * 0.12 INTO incentive
  FROM employee
  WHERE employee_id = 110;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Incentive  = ' || TO_CHAR(incentive));
END;
/
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIbKi.png)

I tried importing MySQL database into Oracle but to no avail, also tried copying the code directly from another website (w3resources), but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: MySQL doesn't understand PL/SQL.

Comment: MySQL uses a different language called SQL/PSM (Procedural SQL).

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE calculate_incentive()
BEGIN
  DECLARE incentive DECIMAL(10, 2);
  
  SELECT salary * 0.12 INTO incentive
  FROM employee
  WHERE employee_id = 110;
  
  SELECT CONCAT('Incentive = ', incentive);
END;
//
DELIMITER ;

CALL calculate_incentive();
THIS IS CODE FOR MYSQL